# Python count and average value of keys in list of dict

Tags: python

I have file with `people_id` and `room_id` column. I read all file into dict.

```
people_id room_id
1   8
2   32
3   8
4   47
5   12
6   8
```

And code

```
report_keys = ['people_id', 'room_id']
report = []
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split('\t')
        d = dict(zip(report_keys, line))
        report.append(d)
```

I would like to count people per room. Eg. for room_id 8 number of people in this room = 3 and average of people in room's.

Output:

```
Room_id 8 = 3 people
Room_id 32 = 1 people
Room_id 47 = 1 people
Room_id 12 = 1 people
```

And Average number of people checked in to one room.

I try to do that

```
for key, value in report:
    print(key, len([item for item in value if item]))
```

But my code print only the same values

Comment: so desired output is what? Would that work: `print(key, sum(int(x) for x in  value))` for the count and `print(key, sum(int(x) for x in  value)/len(value))` for the average?

Comment: Count of people per room and average.

Comment: Post an example of current and desired output, please.

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld I update my question

Comment: When i print out your report i get a list, can you confirm this is as expected?: [{'people_id': 'people_id room_id'}, {'people_id': '1   8'}, {'people_id': '2   32'}, {'people_id': '3   8'}, {'people_id': '4   47'}, {'people_id': '5   12'}, {'people_id': '6   8'}]

Comment: @churchwalk is not, should be `[{'people_id': '1', 'room_id': '8'},{'people_id': '2', 'room_id': '32'},{'people_id': '3', 'room_id': '8'},{'people_id': '4', 'room_id': '47'},{'people_id': '5', 'room_id': 12'},{'people_id': '6', 'room_id': '8'}]`

Comment: @lukassz
It is clear why you get a constant.
For the code to work I had to remove the argument `'\t'`.

Anyhow, you loop over constant key, value pairs with key = 'room_id' and value = 'people_id'. with the length of these strings always being the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change the code how you read the file

```
report = {}
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split('\t')
        report[line[1]] = report.get(line[1],0) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.txt")

df.groupby('room_id').size().to_dict()
{8: 3, 32: 1, 12: 1, 47: 1}
```

Comment: I must use only standard libraries